# Number of days it took to climb the mountain (BdMO 2012 National Primary/Junior question)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

From the [Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad 2012 National Secondary](http://matholympiad.org.bd/questions/bdmo-questions/summary/4-bdmo-2012/21-bdmo-2012-national-primary) (Question 7, or ৭).

> When Tanvir climbed the Tajingdong mountain, on his way to the top he saw it was raining $11$ times. At Tajindong, on a rainy day, it rains either in the morning or in the afternoon; but it never rains twice in the 
>   same day. On his way, Tanvir spent $16$ mornings and $13$ afternoons without rain. How many days did it 
>   take for Tanvir to climb the Tajindong mountain in total?

I tried to solve it using sets but it has not worked out too well. I asked people who did it but most of them gave different answers ,often having a difference of $1$ or $2$. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Contradictory tags?

Comment: @Jp McCarthy,I was not exactly sure what to tag it with.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: I find elementary set theory quite recreational. ;-)  (Oh, you meant...)

Comment: Well, wouldn't it be 3x it rained in the afternoon, leaving 8 rainy days, for each you see a morning or an afternoon, so its 9 sunshine days. 9 afternoons, 9 mornings, 4 rainy afternoons, 4 shiny mornings, 4 rainy mornings, 4 shiny afternoons, 3 rainy afternoons, 3 shiny afternoons. Thats 11 rainy days, and 9 sunshine days, resulting in a 20 day journey.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer,I got it from the junior section of the nationals.Did not know it came in the primary section as well.

Comment: I've formatted your question, as well as provided what I am almost certain is the original source.

Comment: Honestly, I just Googled "When Tanvir climbed the Tajingdong" and this was the first thing that popped up.  Feel free to give a different source.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer,I am not saying this came from a different source.I am just saying I got it from the Junior section,not the primary one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll approach it up front:

Every day is divided in 2 sections:

- morning or rain
- afternoon or rain

Since it says that it can only rain once in a day, it doesn't even need to be accounted for a full day rain, so the number of days is

mornings$ +$ afternoons $+$ rainy times  $ = $ 2 $\times$ amount of days

Thus $16 + 13 + 11 = 2$ $\times$  days -> days = 20
And it fits: 9 sunshine days, 7 morning sunshine, 4 afternoon sunshines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I was getting answers like 23,24 from others .